# Changing name of Default subpage without changing page name WordPress Admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to change the default subpage name to "All Instances" without changing the Parent page name in WordPress admin menu bar. I would like to change the Autoquote Tool to All Instances but want to keep the Autoquote parent page same just like the default subpage of Posts.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option is to manipulate the global `$submenu`. The other is jQuery, but that's not ideal.

So, given a plugin main menu called *Autoquote Tool* and a submenu called *Other Stuff*, here's how to change the first submenu to *All Instances*:

```
global $submenu;
$submenu['autoquote-tool'][0][0] = 'All Instances';
```

Here a `var_dump` for `$submenu['autoquote-tool']`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => All Instances
            [1] => add_users
            [2] => autoquote-tool
            [3] => Autoquote Tool
            [4] => menu-top toplevel_page_autoquote-tool
            [5] => toplevel_page_autoquote-tool
            [6] => http://s.w.org/favicon.ico
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Other Stuff
            [1] => add_users
            [2] => other-stuff
            [3] => Other Stuff
        )

)
```

And the full sample code:

```
add_action('admin_menu', function() 
{
    add_menu_page( 
        'Autoquote Tool', 
        'Autoquote Tool', 
        'add_users', 
        'autoquote-tool', // Submenu ID
        function(){ 
            printf(
                '<h2>%s</h2>',
                __( 'Main page' )
            );
        },
        'http://s.w.org/favicon.ico'
    );  

    add_submenu_page(
        'autoquote-tool',
        'Other Stuff',
        'Other Stuff',
        'add_users',
        'other-stuff',
        function(){ 
            printf(
                '<h2>%s</h2>',
                __( 'Sub page' )
            );
        }
    );

    global $submenu;
    $submenu['autoquote-tool'][0][0] = 'All Instances'; // Submenu ID
});
```

Without modifying the `$submenu`:

[image]

Modified:

[image]